# How reutilize the cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My table have the functionality to delete a row, but when add a new row is writting two labels in the same place, a label above of the other label

a label belong to the deleted row and the other label belong to the new label when add a new row

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell  = UITableViewCell()

        tableView.register(newCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"newCell");
        cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newCell", for: indexPath) as! newCell
        cell.textLabel.text= value

        return  cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing it absolutely wrong. `1` you should register your cell before your table ask you for cell not while its asking. `2` once you registered cell, you should not create cell manually instead ask `tableView` to give you cell that you registered.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary how i give the registred cell?

Comment: look at @nothingwhatsoever's answer, it is right way to load table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, register your cell outside the `cellForRowAt indexPath` function, preferably where you are adding your tableView.

For this instance, register it in `viewDidLoad`

So
`tableView.register(newCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"newCell")`
goes into `viewDidLoad`

for the function, try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newCell", for: indexPath) as! newCell
        cell.textLabel.text= value

        return  cell
    }
```

Hope this helps. Also, provide more context to what is going wrong and what is the intended behaviour.